# IntelliJ IDEA 14 - Java fuzzy code completion not working correctly anymore

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I really liked the fuzzy code completion in IntelliJ.

That means: you typed: ".pln" and IntelliJ suggested: println

But in version 14 this does not work very well anymore.

You can type "ln" to get a suggestion for println, but if you type a letter for which actually a function exists that begins with this letter, the fuzzy search does not work anymore.

For example: If I type "p", only all functions beginning with p are shown.

And when I type "pln" IntelliJ does not suggest anything, since there is no function that begins with "pln". So it does not look for functions that include "p" "l" "n" like println, anymore...

Any idea? Or am I wrong and this was also the behaviour known from version 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching has never worked in such a relaxed way in IntelliJ IDEA. To complete "println", there's no other way than to just write some substring of it. In words with uppercase letters, you can type just them (in any case), e.g. "fis", "FIS", "ins" will all match "FileInputStream".

Comment: Thanks, so maybe I mixed things up with an eclipse plugin called "code recommenders". :-(

Answer (score 0):

Type the initial letters of the **CamelHumps** names, for example:
[image]

So, try type **sout** then enter :

```
System.out.println();
```

Comment: What you are showing in your picture is "Search anywhere". I asked for code completion "<CTRL>+<SPACE>". And "sout" does only work this way since it is a predefined abbrevation that also has nothing to do with the problem I mentioned.